# Android Studio - Google Play Store App missing in Android 12 / API 31 Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I installed that:

[image]

When creating Emulator Device I've chosen this:

[image]

Android 12 is their latest broken mess, why is it not in recommended?

When I run it then doesn't have Google Play Store installed, why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At least, if you choose **Pixel 4, 3a, 3 or 2** as the device definition...

[image: Choose a device definition]

There should appear the **Android 12.0 (Google Play)** image.

[image: Select a system image]

Comment: Yeah it's available on those, thanks... omg somebody need to stop those monkeys from "developing" this mess called android, I'm sick and tired of it! Having to change stuff in the app just because they keep introducing new useless broken bs

Comment: Further, the Pixel 3 has a "Play Store" icon shown next to it on the device selection screen. So why should one expect to *not* have it starting Android 12?...

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use Android 12 Google Play image with any of emulated configuration:

1. Create emulated device with any possible system image (do not run the device yet)
2. Edit .android/avd/<your emulator name>/config.ini and replace a line with system image with:

> image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\

3. Save config.ini and run emulator

Comment: Didnt work. it crashes after showing the emulator skin.

Comment: It works, thanks! Note, it is really necessary to edit the file before the first run of this AVD.